# MySQL - Duplicate PK when trigger is fired, but not when record is directly inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have the following MySQL trigger.  It is fired for an update on tbl_users.  It will either update tbl_user_stats with some information if there already exists a record for that day, or it will insert a new record in tbl_user_stats if there is not a record for that day.  action_date is the PK of tbl_user_stats and it holds the date.

```
drop trigger if exists trigger_update_user_stats_upgrades_and_downgrades$$


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_user_stats_upgrades_and_downgrades AFTER UPDATE ON tbl_users
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE date_now int;
IF NEW.premium <> OLD.premium THEN

    SET date_now = (SELECT count(*) from tbl_user_stats WHERE DATE(action_date) = CURDATE());
    IF date_now > 0 THEN
        IF NEW.premium = 0 THEN
            UPDATE tbl_user_stats SET downgrades = downgrades + 1 WHERE DATE(action_date) = CURDATE();
        ELSE
            UPDATE tbl_user_stats SET upgrades = upgrades + 1 WHERE DATE(action_date) = CURDATE();  
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF NEW.premium = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_user_stats (action_date, downgrades) values (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 1);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO tbl_user_stats (action_date, upgrades) values (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 1);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;
END$$
```

Towards the bottom, I am inserting CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY for testing purposes. I am trying to simulate an update on tbl_users being performed on the next day.  So if today is 11/22/13 I want to pretend that a record in tbl_users is being updated on 11/23/13.  If the trigger works correctly, tbl_user_stats should have a new record inserted with the action_date of 11/23/13.

The problem is that when I try to update tbl_users, I get an error that says "Duplicate primary key 11/23/13". However, there is no primary key in tbl_user_stats set to 11/23/13.  When I manually insert a new record into tbl_user_stats using 11/23/13 as the PK, there is no problem.  The problem only arises when I try to update tbl_users.  Why am I getting the Duplicate primary key error?

Comment: Can you post the structure of your tables with some data and the `UPDATE` statement that causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced this error.
This occurs because you're checking condition of "date_now" is checking for `CURDATE()`
when you're inserting with `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`
To simulate the next day, you should change all your date comparisons to `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

[sqlFiddle code with all CURDATE() changed to CURDATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e0ee/1/1) gets rid of the error.
To reproduce error, just change

```
SET date_now = (SELECT count(*) from t2 WHERE DATE(start_date) = CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

to

```
SET date_now = (SELECT count(*) from t2 WHERE DATE(start_date) = CURDATE());`
```